# Is Java BitSet thread safe for concurrent readonly operations

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, bitset

I have multiple threads in my application accessing a BitSet concurrently. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) says:

> A BitSet is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization.

It doesn't say if it is not safe for reading or writing. Can anybody explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BitSet` is only safe for read-only operations if there is a "happens before" relationship between the last action that initializes the `BitSet` and the actions that read it.

The simplest way to achieve this is using a `final`.  For example:

```
public class BitsetHolder {
    private final BitSet b;

    public BitSetHolder() {
        b = new BitSet();
        // operations to initialize b.
    }

    public BitSet getBitSet() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

This is sufficient to ensure that the `BitSet` is "safely published".

However, if you don't do something like this, there is no guarantee that threads that read the `BitSet` will see the fully initialized state.

Another alternative to explicit synchronization is to use a `volatile` variable to hold the reference to the `BitSet`.  However, that inserts a memory barrier on each read and write of the variable.

---

Note that the same reasoning applies to all non-thread-safe "effectively immutable" objects; i.e. objects that have mutable state which you don't mutate.